# Why would Chrome interfere with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, google-chrome, timeout

I have SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000.5) installed on my laptop for local / personal use. I have a C# application that fetches podcast feeds to parse the XML for information. It does this once per hour. Execution time is generally very fast.

At times, however, the SQL Server will time out for both the app I've written and any queries I try to execute directly in SSMS.

Until I shut down my Google Chrome browser, at which point my stalled queries instantly execute without further issue.

I've tried to find information on this, but most of what I've found has to do with running stuff FROM Chrome accessing SQL Server, which is not what's happening. Something Chrome is doing is causing SQL Server to timeout. I'm GUESSING some sort of deadlock situation for some resource? (Just a guess!)

It doesn't seem to matter if I have Edge, IE, Opera, or FireFox open. Just Chrome, as far as I can tell.

Is this something known, and can anyone point me to how to fix it?

I've run SQL Server Profiler during these episodes. In fact, it happened as I was typing this post. It took forever to connect, then just showed the queries taking forever to run. Nothing "useful," at least not toward answering my question.

Comment: You need to look at the wait types that your queries are experiencing. Maybe the SQL Server is memory starved until you free some up and it is waiting for memory grants

Comment: How much memory on your system, how much memory is Chrome using, if you leave Chrome off for 24 hours how much memory is SQL Server using? (Don't look at Task Manager, since it lies; look at perfmon or DMVs.)

Comment: Have you configured SQL Server's Max memory setting? This should be approx 10-12% less than total physical ram on a system dedicated to SQL Server, with other apps probably more like 20-25% less or more. Chrome uses memory like an Ariane rocket uses liquid oxygen.

Comment: Install the [WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) script and run this when the process appears to hang, it should tell you what resource it is waiting on or what is blocking.

Comment: Both Chrome and SQL Server will often use as much memory as they can get their hands on. This often results in memory being paged to disk. You should give SQL Server service account the right to "Lock pages in memory"

Comment: And cap the SQL Server Max Memory to reserve memory for your other programs.